# Generic Period Range Method in ComboBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I would like someone guide me on this.
I have to use in several aspx pages the same method to calculate the range date, when I select from a combobox a period.
For example I have in a page a combo with periods (current month sales, last month sales, last year sales, current year sales) and in another page a combo with periods (current week expense, current month expense etc..) the result is the same, give me a date range (start and end date) but not all the combos has the same period (one has: month, week, year and another: month and year).
What can I do to made it generic? Was thinking in a Enum bit flag or a user control...someone can give me a hand?
Thanks!

Comment: Plz someone can give me an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you'll need to do:

1. Place time-stamp strings into the combobox option *values*, like "2013-03-01:2013-03-31" for "This month's expenses", for example.  You will need a function to get the start and end for this month, last month, this week, etc.  I have written an example below.
2. Keep your combobox option text the same (e.g., "This month's expenses").
3. Read in the combobox option values, and use a date/time string parser to get the ranges.

The code for getting last week, last month, etc. would be something like:

```
public static void GetPeriod(string selected_period, out DateTime start, out DateTime end)
{
    switch (selected_period)
    {
        case "last year":
            start = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year - 1, 1, 1);
            end = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1);
            break;
        case "this year":
            start = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1);
            end = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year + 1, 1, 1).AddDays(-1);
            break;
        case "last month":
            start = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1).AddMonths(-1);
            end = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year + 1, DateTime.Today.Month, 1).AddDays(-1);
            break;
        case "this month":
            start = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1);
            end = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year + 1, DateTime.Today.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
            break;
        case "last week":
            start = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
            while (start.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                start = start.AddDays(-1);
            end = start.AddDays(6);
            break;
        case "this week":
            start = DateTime.Today;
            while (start.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                start = start.AddDays(-1);
            end = start.AddDays(6);
            break;
    }
}
```

Then you would just convert the start and end into a string that you put into the combobox option values.

Comment: I already has that switch case, but I dont want to repeat it in al pages. I was thinking to create a combobox webcontrol which inherits from RadComboBox, and create a property Items type enum bit flag, populate the items I need depend of the page for exmaple page 1 (week, month, last year) page 2 (week, month, quarter) but dont know how to do it, so then just have to create a combobox type my custom combobox set my properties and itself do all. but how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a little too long for a comment, so I'm creating another answer.  I have not used RadComboBox, but I have created my own custom .ascx controls in VS 2010.  Here's what you need to do:

1. Create the .ascx control
2. Add an ASP.NET combobox in it (or perhaps a RadComboBox)
3. Create a control property (string) that lists the options you want to display, e.g., "year,week,month".  That way, you can change the options per page in the HTML without any other coding required.
4. In your .ascx control code, change the display options based on the custom property in #2.
5. Create functions in the control to get the start and end of the period, based on which option is selected.

That way, all you have to do in a given page is insert your custom control, specify the custom property, and then call GetStart or GetEnd when needed.  All other coding is taken care of in the control itself.  I imagine you could do this with RadComboBox as well, though I've never used it.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your answer. What I was thinking was to create a user control CustomCombox which extends from RadCombobx and there I will have a method that gives me the period range. I didnt understand what you meand with Create a control property...could you explain me plz?
Thanks in advance!! Sorry cant make new answer, system dont let me.

Comment: If you create a custom .ascx control, you can create custom properties that allow you to specify options right in the HTML--for example,<uc1:MyComboBox PeriodsToShow="week,month,year" ID="MyComboBox1" runat="server" />.  In the code-behind, you would have something like: public string PeriodsToShow, and then specify get/set assessors.

Comment: See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information.

Comment: By the way Peter with this PeriodsToShow="week,month,year" how do I set (populate) my combo with this values? How do I ask, if (PeriodsToShow= week,month,year) then do this, etc... would be proper to use a flag enum? Thanks!

Comment: I would split the string using the comma, and then loop through the resulting string array, processing each item individually.  For instance, process the "week" entry by adding two items: "Last week" and "This week" to your combobox.  [.NET Split string documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)